# Prevent an iterator from being affected by changes to a variable used in its definition

Tags: python, iterator, immutability

## Edit/solution

Here's an example that more closely mimics my real problem, and a solution implementing the comment by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe). Thanks!

```
import io
import heapq


# THIS DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED
files = dict(f0=io.StringIO("first line\nsecond line"),
             f1=io.StringIO("FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE"))
iterators = ((line.split() + [fname] for line in f)
             for fname, f in files.items())
list(heapq.merge(*iterators))
# [['FIRST', 'LINE', 'f0'],
#  ['SECOND', 'LINE', 'f0'],
#  ['first', 'line', 'f0'],
#  ['second', 'line', 'f0']]

# THIS DOES WORK
files = dict(f0=io.StringIO("first line\nsecond line"),
             f1=io.StringIO("FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE"))
iterators = ((lambda x=fname: ((line.split() + [x]) for line in f))(fname)
             for fname, f in files.items())
list(heapq.merge(*iterators))
# [['FIRST', 'LINE', 'f1'],
#  ['SECOND', 'LINE', 'f1'],
#  ['first', 'line', 'f0'],
#  ['second', 'line', 'f0']]
```

## Original question

How can I make the Python code below produce `[(1, 0), (1, 1)]` instead of `[(2, 0), (2, 1)]`? That is, I wish the result wasn't affected by changes to `const` made after the definition of the iterator `it`.

```
>>> const = 1
>>> var = range(2)
>>> it = ((const, i) for i in var)
>>> const = 2
>>> list(it)
[(2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

My real-world problem is to [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) multiple files without keeping all their contents in memory. I'd like to programmatically generate iterators that report the file name together with each line of each file, e.g. `("file2.txt", "this is line 1")`. Currently, all my iterators end up reporting the same filename.

Comment: You could create a new temporary variable for it to capture instead: `tmp = const` then `it = ((tmp, i) for i in var)`.

Comment: Or use a `lambda` to create a new scope with that value set: `it = (lambda x=const: ((x, i) for i in var))(const)`

Comment: So encapsulate the generator expression in a function? `const` is a closure, so yes, this is entirely expected. Generator expressions are no different from functions in this respect. Closures are 'live'.

Comment: You should write an answer with a solution (and then accept it), not edit it into the question.

Comment: @River, thanks for letting me know. However, I don't see any "Your Answer" box at the bottom. Could there be anything preventing me from answering, e.g. the [duplicate] tag?

Comment: @JonOlavVik oh yea, this is due to it being closed as a duplicate... I've rolled back my edit. Just keep in mind for future that answers belong in the answers section =)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the generator expression from the module scope into a function, so the `const` value is read from the function scope and further changes to `const` do not influence the evaluation of the generator expression:

```
def hide_gen(const):
    return ((const, i) for i in [0, 1])

const = 1
it = hide_gen(const)
const = 2
print(list(it))
# [(1, 0), (1, 1)]
```